# How do I "wait" until a component has updated (re-rendered) with Enzyme and Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, axios, enzyme

I have a parent component that does the following:

1. Generates a form with various `input` fields
2. When the submit button is clicked, a `POST` request with the `<form>` data is made to the server using `axios`
3. If an `Error` response is returned, an error message is rendered inside a `<span>` element on the form

I'm writing the following test for this scenario

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

jest.mock('axios');

it('displays an error when the submit fails', async () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);

  // Fill in form input fields with text (not shown)
  // ....
  // ....

  // Mock the axios `POST` call to return an error
  const errorResponse = { response: { data: { errors: [{ title: 'Some error' }] } } }
  axios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.reject(errorResponse));

  // Click Submit and wait on the axios Promise to complete
  const submit = wrapper.find('.my-component__submit-btn').first();
  await submit.simulate('click');

  // Check if error was rendered on the form
  wrapper.update();
  const error = wrapper.find('.my-component__submit-error').first();
  expect(error).to.have.text('Some error'); // This fails!
});
```

The last `expect()` fails - no error is set but I expect one to exist.

However if I add an artificial delay via `setTimeout`, it passes. So clearly it's an issue where the React component tree does not update before the `expect()` checks it.

Is there a clean way to "wait" on the React tree to re-render without using `setTimeout`?

I thought `wrapper.update()` would do this, but it doesn't seem to.

Thanks!

Comment: Please, don't describe your code but rather post it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Waiting for a promise that Axios returns will probably help but it depends.

Comment: Can you try adding [done();](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous.html)  after your last `expect`? Though you are already using `async-await`. An asynchronous call/promise might have been left out.

Comment: @jegtugado - the `done()` doesn't work here unfortunately. From reading those docs, it seems like calling `done()` is a way to indicate to Jest that your callback or async process has fired. That works great for promises but in my case I'm waiting till the *render* is completed, and I don't see a way of doing that unless I call `done()` from the component itself (e.g. I pass it in as a `prop`).

Comment: Posting your component (`<MyComponent />`) code might help to give better answer.

Comment: A component will only re-render if a change was detected. Can you verify that the component's state has changed?

Comment: Isn't Event that change state suppose to be wrapped in `act(() => {...});` ? This way it will update the error state. After that the `wrapper.update()` should render the error state in the form. I have it to work like that with `act`, don't know if it's what you're missing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to wait for all promises to resolve.
Define:

```
const waitForPromises = () => new Promise(setImmediate);
```

Then, after the component has rendered, wait:

```
await waitForPromises()
```

This, though working in most cases, will still not work if the component is internally updating its state, without triggering these state updates from its properties.

I believe when the latter is the case, this is just an untestable pattern, and requires change in the application design approach, rather than the testing methods.